# splitting lists and storing in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a list such as

```
L = ['B0','B1','C1','C2','D1','D3']
```

Then How do I split the list into values and keys and store it in a dictionary in the following form:-

```
{ 'B':['0','1'],
  'C':['1','2'],
  'D':['1','3']}
```

Comment: Interesting problem, why was the question downvoted? (maybe because the asker didn't show what has been tried so far)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
L = ['B0','B1','C1','C2','D1','D3']
d = {}
for i in L:
    d.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[1])

>>> d
{'B': ['0', '1'], 'C': ['1', '2'], 'D': ['1', '3']}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over the list and break each string element to create a dictionary.  Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['B0','B1','C1','C2','D1','D3']
d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in l:
    d[key].append(value)

print d
```

Comment: You can simply your code by unpacking each string, e.g, `for key, value in : l`, and then you can skip the next two lines.